# RegEx to validate Date Format Masks

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm looking to write a RegEx to validate user inputted date formats like "DD/MM/YYYY" (NOT date validation)

I'm new to RegEx, but so far i have the following:

```
(D{2}|M{2}|Y{2,4})[-|/]?(D{2}|M{2})[-|/]?(D{2}|M{2}|Y{2,4})
```

This matches the following date formats:

- DD/MM/YYYY

  MM/DD/YYYY

  DD-MM-YYYY

  MM-DD-YYYY

  DDMMYYYY

  MMDDYYYY

  YYYYMMDD

  YYYYDDMM

  YYYY/MM/DD

  YYYY/DD/MM

  YYYY-MM-DD

  YYYY-DD-MM

  DD/MM/YY

  MM/DD/YY

  DD-MM-YY

  MM-DD-YY

  DDMMYY

  MMDDYY

  YYMMDD

  YYDDMM

  YY/MM/DD

  YY/DD/MM

  YY-MM-DD

  YY-DD-MM

But unfortunately, also matches the following:

- DDMMDD

  YYMMYYYY

  MMMMMM

Is there any way to only match the formats specified in the first list? The RegEx will be being used in VBA form validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative backreferences to ensure that you don't repeat any previous entries:

```
^(D{2}|M{2}|(YY){1,2})[-|\/]?(?!\1)(D{2}|M{2})[-|\/]?((?!\1|\3)(D{2}|M{2}|(YY){1,2}))$
```

The negative backreference (?!\1) & (?!\1|\3) prevent repetition of the entries.

Also, Y{2,4} matches 'YYY' so I changed that to (YY){1,2}.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested for VBA but how about this:

```
^(((MM(?<s>[-/])?DD|DD(?<s>[-/])?MM)(?(s)[-/])?(YY|YYYY))|((YY|YYYY)(?<s>[-/])?(MM(?(s)[-/])DD|DD(?(s)[-/])MM)))$
```

The thought process was that there are four possible combinations ignoring separators and number of digits for a year. These are:

D M Y

M D Y

Y M D

Y D M

So this can be split into two groups - year at the start or year at the end:

```
^
(((MM(?<s>[-/])?DD|DD(?<s>[-/])?MM)(?(s)[-/])?(YY|YYYY))
|
((YY|YYYY)(?<s>[-/])?(MM(?(s)[-/])DD|DD(?(s)[-/])MM)))
$
```

I also add a named capture group to the separator just to ensure that at least two of the same character exist if present.